# Ending a Case Early

Tags: vb6, exit, select-case

So I have something like the following in Vb6;

```
Select case Case

case "Case0"
...

case "Case1"
  if Condition Then
     Exit Select
  End If
  *Perform action*

case "Case2"
...

End Select
```

But for some reason my `Exit Select` throws the error `Expected: Do or For or Sub or Function or Property`. I know, not pretty. Should I be using something else? I could just use `if` statements and not exit the case early, but this would require duplicate code, which I want to avoid. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update**

Tried changing `Exit Select` to `End Select` and got the error `End Select without Select Case`. It is definitely within a `Select Case` and an `End Select`.

Comment: Is that your actual code? You have defined `Case1` twice, if so.

Comment: What are the data types of your enumerated variable and the values you're comparing it to?

Comment: @Widor The variable is a DB call of a String and it's being compared to Strings also.

Comment: Can you update your code to be valid VB, because it would throw all sorts of errors at present and you need to rule them out first. E.g.`Case Case1` should be `Case "Case1"` etc.

Comment: Waaaaaay too much code for me to just copy across and it was working fine before I began to edit this case statement so we can rule out problems with the rest of the code. Plus the compiler is specifically pointing to the `Exit Select`.

Comment: Sorry - just noticed this is VB6 - see answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VB doesn't have a facility to exit a `Select` block.
Instead, you'll need to make the contents conditional, possibly inverting your `Exit Select` conditional.

```
Select case Case 

case "Case0" 
... 

case "Case1" 
  If Not Condition Then 
    *Perform action* 
  End If 

case "Case2" 
... 

End Select
```

Which will have exactly the same end result.

Comment: +1. And make "perform action" into a subroutine for readability

Comment: The logic was quite complicated in the real version and it would have just been handy to have had a `End Select`, but I ended up going with something along these lines anyways.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as stated. Sorry but in some cases, you really do want to exit early.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson I've just added an opening paragraph explaining a bit more. Hopefully that's better?

Answer (score 5):

There is no `Exit Select` Statement in VB6 - only VB.NET

Have a look at the language reference for the [Exit Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243366%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) - there is *no* mention of `Exit Select`

Best option is to refactor your select statements into a new subroutine and then just `Exit Sub`

Comment: @killianmcc - they all work fine in VB6 - it is the VB6 language reference!

Comment: Sorry, meaning will they work to get me out of a `case` early?

Comment: @killianmcc - have a look at my edited answer above for a possible solution

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, VB6 doesn't have the `Exit Select` clause available.

This is ony available in VB.NET!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Do
    Select case Case

    case "Case0"
    ...

    case "Case1"
      if Condition Then
         Exit Do
      End If
      *Perform action*

    case "Case2"
    ...

    End Select
Loop While False
```

Edit: Btw, I wouldn't hesitate to use `GoTo` in this case (and not only this).

Comment: Agreed on `GoTo`. I'm not sure I could endorse the `Do ... Loop While False` though... :p

Comment: @Deanna `do { ... } while(0)` is very popular plain C idiom for early exit (and correct macro expansion). I really do hope VB6 equivalent `Do/Loop` is a noop for the compiler as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer this old question the other way you can also use GoTo:

```
Select case Case

case "Case0"
...

case "Case1" 'you can use not condition as stated

  if Condition Then GoTo Exit_select
  *Perform action*

case "Case2"
...
Exit_select:
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

just discovered some thing very trivial does the trick:

```
Select case Case 

case "Case0" 
... 

case "Case1" 
  A=A

case "Case2" 
... 

End Selec
```

Answer (score 0):

there is always GOTO to jump to a label at the end.